# get configurable product ordered quantity from quote

Tags: magento-1.7, quote, ce-1.8.1.0

I am using below code for fetching the ordered quantity for products, the value is correctly fetched for simple product. but in case of configurable product the quantity remains 1.

```
foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item){
        $buyrequest = $item->getBuyRequest();
        $qty = $buyrequest->getQty();
}
```

i even tried `$item->getQtyOrdered()`.

Answer (score 2):

To get the items from a quote I would suggest using `getAllVisibleItems` then you can simply call `getQty()` on each item.

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load(68);
foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){
    $qty = $item->getQty();
}
```

The reason for using `getAllVisibleItems` is that this deals with parent products and so will only give you the items that would show to the user.

Answer (score 1):

When configurable product is being added to the quote it is presented by 2 quote items: 1 for product itself and 1 for its option (simple product). So if you want to get ordered quantity you need to do it like this.

```
foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){
    if ($item->getHasChildren()) {
        $qty = 0;
        foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
            $qty += $child->getQty();
        }
    } else {
        $qty = $item->getQty();
    }
}
```

`$item->getHasChildren()` means the case I described in the start of answer. So in that case you need to get only children qtys